# What is wrong in my code?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have tried to solve the equation using javascript but it does not return the right value. Where am I wrong?

Code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Click the button to calculate t</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>Enter R1:
    <input type="text" id="txt1" name="text1">Enter R2:
    <input type="text" id="txt2" name="text2">Enter c1:
    <input type="text" id="txt3" name="text3">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
        var z = document.getElementById("txt3").value;
        var t = 0.7*(x + 2*y)*z;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What value are you expecting and what do you get back?

Comment: x y and z are strings. Convert them to numbers.

Comment: I am giving input, x=5; y=11 and z=0.02 it backs 60.5 while i expecting 1.54

Answer (score 2):

You can also convert the values in the input items to an integer before calculate your expression.
Something like:

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt3").value);
if (isNaN(x) || isNaN(y) || isNaN(z)) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The values inserted are not valid";   
} 
else {
    var t = 0.7*(x + 2*y)*z;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}
```

In the example I also checked that values inserted are valid numbers

Comment: same thing is happening. i am expecting the value should be 0.378 at x=5; y=11 & z=0.02. it is giving me 60.5

Comment: Using parseFloat instead of parseInt should work also with float numbers

Answer (score -1):

```
    var x = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("txt3").value;
    var a= 2*y; `enter code here`enter code here
    var b= a+x;
    var t= 0.7*b*z

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;

enter code here
```